# sas matrix to dataset with variable names

Tags: sas

I have following matrix:
[image: matrix]

I would like to covert it to SAS dataset in following format:
[image: SAS dataset]

`lastname` is missing if it is the same as the previous one, and I have thousands of names. How should I do this?

Comment: What created the matrix? Is the picture of the matrix some printed output?

Comment: You say Matrix - do you mean a SAS IML matrix or is it in a matrix format in Excel? If Excel, have you already imported it into SAS?

Comment: This is most likely a First observation carried forward problem and needs you to use retain. To stay within SO rules please post what you've tried.

Comment: It's a matrix in excel, I havent imported it into sas yet, not sure how should I read it into SAS so that it's can be proceesed to the format I needed

Comment: Your column headers look shifted to the left by one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell SAS to import the "matrix" without names. This will both let you be able to read the names as data and also force all variables to be character strings.  So essentially you will get something like this data set.

```
data have ;
  length f1-f6 $32 ;
  infile cards dsd truncover ;
  input f1-f6 ;
cards;
,,L1,,L2
,,F1,F2,F3,F4
,,,,,,                  
L3,F5,1,2,3,4
,F6,5,6,7,8
L4,F7,9,10,11,12
,F8,13,14,15,16
;;;;
```

You can then process the dataset and generate your from/to name variables.  First make an array that references all of the variables.  Then make two temporary arrays to store the column header names.  Then when you read each row you can find the names and values from that row and output them.

```
data want ;
  set have nobs=nobs ;
  array x _character_ ;
  array ln (200) $32 _temporary_;
  array fn (200) $32 _temporary_;
  length from_lastn lag_lastn from_firstn to_lastn to_firstn $32 ;
  from_lastn = coalescec(x(1),lag_lastn);
  lag_lastn = from_lastn ;
  retain lag_lastn ;
  from_firstn = x(2) ;
  if _n_=1 then do i=3 to dim(x) ;
    ln(i)=coalescec(x(i),ln(i-1));
  end;
  if _n_=2 then do i=3 to dim(x) ;
    fn(i)=x(i);
  end;
  if _n_>3 then do i=3 to dim(x) ;
    to_lastn = ln(i);
    to_firstn= fn(i);
    value=input(x(i),comma32.);
    output;
  end;
  keep from_lastn from_firstn to_lastn to_firstn value ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only import flat files into SAS, so you'll need to clean up your headings a bit first.

Follow the instructions here to get rid of blank "lastnames" along the top and side:
http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/771-excel-fill-blank-cells-with-value-above.html

Once there are no blanks, I think it would be easiest to concatenate the first and last names together into one cell. Something like =CONCATENATE(C1,C2) along the top, and =CONCATENATE(A4|B4) along the side should do the trick.

Copy and paste the concatenated *values only* over themselves to remove the formulas. Then delete the original values.

You should end up with something like this:[Screenshot of Excel Data Ready to Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGNmB.png)
.

Now, import into SAS and stack the values with a program that looks something like this:

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA = import_from_excel
OUT=data_stacked
;
BY Names;
VAR 
    lastname1firstname1 
    lastname1firstname2 
    lastname1firstname3 
    lastname1firstname4 
    lastname1firstname5 
    lastname2firstname1 
    lastname2firstname2 
    lastname2firstname3 
    lastname2firstname4 
    lastname2firstname5
;
RUN;
```

You'll obviously have to change the lastnameXfirstnameX values to match what you have, but it should be as easy as copying and pasting column A from Excel.

Hopefully, you don't have so many names as to overwhelm the proc transpose, but cleaning it up and stacking it is the basic idea.